# Remove trailing space from shell variable in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I have a tcsh script that does this:

```
  set _iterm2_truncated_prompt=`echo "$prompt" | sed -e 's/ $//'`
```

However, this fails for certain values of $prompt. Here's a minimal (albeit silly and unrealistic) example:

```
set prompt='{['
set _iterm2_truncated_prompt=`echo "$prompt" | sed -e 's/ $//'`
```

Which produces the error:

```
Missing ].
```

Seems like "quotes" are ignored inside `backticks`.

Short of creating a temp file, which seems really hard to do in a portable and secure way, is this even possible to do in tcsh? I'd like it to work for any possible value of `$prompt`.

I know that csh/tcsh scripting is best avoided. Since some of my users do use tcsh, it's a necessary evil here. Ultimately this script must modify the shell's `$prompt` variable, so a bit of tcsh scripting is truly unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

The following command:

```
set noglob
```

will turn off many kinds of substitutions--at least enough for what I'm expecting to see in normal usage. Then

```
unset noglob
```

afterwards.